# Implenting Credit card processing within PHP MySql Site

Tags: php, credit-card, e-commerce

I am developing an Ecommerce website and I would like to implement Credit/Debit card processing within the site.

I would like to know if there are any good PHP scripts which fully implement this and the payment gateways that provide this service.

Also the website will have a Money Back guarantee feature in the event of cancelling of orders and so on. So how can this also be implemented using Credit/Debit cards i.e. I want to be able to refund the customers in the event of a cancelled order.

The site/service will be offered in Africa and Paypal isnt present.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of credit card do you want to support? (Visa, etc..)

Comment: The credit card which is in use here is Visa, so that would be ny first choice

Answer (score 2):

You need to find someone to process your credit card payments first. eg Paypal or SagePay.

They will provide you with all the documentation on integrating with the payment gateway, and all the ones I have used in the past have included PHP sample code.

Here are some handy links for you...

- [Paypal Developer Docs](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation)
- [Google Checkout](https://checkout.google.com/seller/?hl=en&gl=GB)
- [SagePay](http://www.sagepay.com/) (UK credit card
  processing)

**Update:** Since you are trying to offer this service in Africa, I would recommend contacting your local big bank to see what services they offer. All the major banks in the UK and the US offer their own gateways (or point you in the direction of their preferred partner), and I would imagine that would be true everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

http://pear.php.net/package/Validate_Finance_CreditCard